# Can I append configurations to Gradle's buildscript?

Tags: gradle

I have a gradle build script (main script) that import another build script via next statement 
`apply from: "../init.gradle"`.
The imported script contains next configuration for build:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        ...
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.9.RELEASE'
        ...
    }
}
```

In the main script I want to add some new plugins. Can I do this or if I pass a new closure to the buildscript, it will override configuration defined in the init script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't override at all.

https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:buildscript(groovy.lang.Closure)

```
buildscript { }
```

> Configures the build script classpath for this project. The given
>   closure is executed against this project's ScriptHandler. The
>   ScriptHandler is passed to the closure as the closure's delegate.

You can add as many `closure` you want

Answer (score 0):

you can do this: normally configurations are merged, but have in mind you're trying to add buildscript which is a special case of gradle and this don't merge.